# how to ge the filled grid view data to database

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a grid filled  with data.so i need, that data to the another table in the database.
i am using a button by clilcking that button data in grid is to be stored in the database.
i have tried but how to retrieve the grind indexes which are filled with data

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the data of gridview by using for loop, please see below code:
Suppose your Gridview is "gv"

for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)gv.Rows[i].FindControl("txtorder");
               int id = Convert.ToInt32(gv.DataKeys[_count].Value);
// You can get gridview data and pass it into another table by firing insert query here.
            }